# originalRenderPage is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am facing such issue in my new nextjs app.
The problem started to show itself when I used props to add a carousel to my project. It gives a problem that the originalRenderPage in Document.js is not defined.
Thanks for your help

```js
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages\_document.js (26:25) @ Object.ctx.renderPage

  24 |   const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage
  25 | 
> 26 |   ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
     |                         ^
  27 |     enhanceApp: WrappedComponent => props => sheets.collect(<WrappedComponent {...props} />)
  28 |   })
```

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles'
import {Html} from "next/document";

class _Document extends Document {
  render () {
    return (
      <Html lang='pt-BR' dir='ltr'>
        <Head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

_Document.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets()
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

  ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
    enhanceApp: WrappedComponent => props => sheets.collect(<WrappedComponent {...props} />)
  })

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()]
  }
}

export default _Document
```

Comment: Can you share your solution, thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember, since I didn't do the props operation in my code, the information I made in the .map was causing me to get this error. Adding props to my code fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')`

It's happening because of this line

`const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets()`

Fix it to

`const sheets = new ServerStyleSheet()`

https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#example

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I have another code error, I found the solution.